# eVar visits sum more than 100%?

Tags: adobe-analytics

i have an **eVar30** that gets set on every page on site.
possible values for **eVar30=[a,b,c,d,e]**

when i run report on **eVar30** for **visits, instances, page view**.

the sum of all different segments of **[a,b,c,d,e]** sums up to roughly 100% for **instances and page view**

but for **visits** the sum is significantly higher than 100%. and the count for **visits** is bigger than **instances and page view**. (*because **visits are session** based, i expect that **visits** numbers should be less than **instances or pageviews**?*)

wondering if anybody would know whether this is an indication of **code error on my end** or some usage case that could cause this result.

thanks in advance

Heres the report, see that **None** has almost no **page views, or instances**
does this means i m over reporting? but should all 3 key metrics be inflated as well?

`Visits        PageViews     Instance        Order
segA    158-58.8%     187-51.0%     187-51.1%       7-51.9%
segB    134-49.9%     179-48.8%     179-48.8%       7-48.1%

None    128-47.3%     3-0.1%        0-0.0%          0-0.0%`

Answer (score 3):

Since you're setting this on every page, each visit will have multiple line items in the eVar30 report. The same visit can be duplicated across each line item so the total of the report will be more than 100%. If you had one visit hit 3 pages, setting three different values for eVar30, you visit total would be 3 for that single visit.

Comment: thanks @BrettAHale, but shouldnt the count for **instances** and **page view** also go up in this case? i only see **visits** having a higher value for all **[a,b,c,d,e]** segments and add up to more than 100%.  **instances and pageview** both match up to each other and add up to 100

Comment: @yoshi Since the eVar will get set once on a page view, also being one instance, usually all page views and instances will be equal and total up to 100% neatly. So during a page view, it will get set to one value, one time. During a visit, it can get set to many values, many times, hence the duplication and the report total not adding up to 100%.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I added the report example that i m trying to understand. 

@BrettAHale

i m still trying to understand the data. i want to figure out if this is an error on my end for over reporting (should inflate all 3 metrics?) 

thanks for the patience

Comment: @yoshi how are you setting evar30? If you set it on all pages, the fact that none has 128 would concern me. Also, 128 visits with 3 page views doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just because of de-duplication of visit the percentage is higher than 100% which doesn't happen in case of page view or instances.